# Binding ComboBox to Lookup<char, string>

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to bind the 'DisplayMemberPath' of a WPF combo box to a `Lookup<char, string>)`

and I'm not getting anywhere, this is my xaml...

```
<ComboBox        
           ItemsSource="{Binding Dimensions}"
           DisplayMemberPath ="Element"                               
           SelectedValuePath="Key"                           
           SelectedValue=...
 />
```

If I bind 'DisplayMemberPath' to "Key" I can see the LookUp key so I know it sort of works, however I want to bind to Element part of the LookUp to see the display text.

I've also tried 'Grouping' in the DisplayMemberPath path but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type being displayed is a `Grouping` or `IGrouping` as you noted. The only [available property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx) on that type is `Key` which does not provide what you want.

You can either adjust the type you are binding to which would allow you access to additional properties or you can make use of an [IValueConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ivalueconverter) and extract the data via the available methods on the `IGrouping` type.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx
You will see this "Gets the collection of values indexed by the specified key."
If you switch to a dictionary then you it would work. You can't bind DisplayMemberPath to a collection.